# Calling C++ function from C code linkage errors (using gcc for linking)

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker-errors

I am writting a "library" in C++ that is supposed to be used also by C code. I have followed the process as such:
 - Using g++ and gcc compilers (as they are compatible).
 - Used `extern "C"` in functions to be used by C code.
 - My top level uses a wrapper function with signature that can be understood by a C compiler.
 - Compiled to objective files the C++ code (with g++).
 - Compiled my client code file with gcc.
 - Edit: **Tried/want to link them with gcc (or ld) (and not g++)**.

An *MCV example* would be the following:

**mymalloc.h**

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* for size_t */

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
void *mymalloc(size_t cbytes);

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
void myfree(void *ptr);
```

**allocator.cpp**

```
#include "allocator.h"
#include "mymalloc.h"

Allocator *  Allocator::instance = 0;

extern "C" void *mymalloc(size_t cbytes){
    Allocator *allocator = Allocator::getInstance();
    return allocator->allocateFor(cbytes);
}

extern "C" void myfree(void *ptr){
    Allocator *allocator = Allocator::getInstance();
    allocator->freePtr(ptr);
}

...
```

That source file defines the functions to be used by C code, as well as methods of `allocator.h` which by itself includes other C++ stuff.

My C client file (**cclient.c**) is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mymalloc.h"

int main(void){
    void *p = mymalloc(500);
    printf("%p\n", p);
    return 0;
}
```

---

I was under the impression that since I have those wrapper functions at my top level and since their declarations can be viewed by C code everything should be ok but I am getting linking errors: (sample/example shown)

```
./libmymalloc.a(allocator.o): In function `Allocator::getInstance()':
allocator.cpp:(.text+0x3cf): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
allocator.cpp:(.text+0x3fa): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
./libmymalloc.a(allocator.o):(.data.DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0[DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0]+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
```

The way I am compiling and linking, in favor of clarity, is

```
g++ -c allocator.cpp
... (same for the rest .cpp files)
gcc -c cclient.c
gcc cclient.o allocator.o ...(all other c++ objectives)...
```

---

**Edit** (After first three answers): I know that I can link using g++. I would be interested in how to link with the C compiler, so that someone having available only gcc and the objectives (or a library from those) could link on his own.

(This question could be a duplicate, but I have read all other questions in SO and I couldn't deduct what I was doing wrong.)

Comment: What's in `allocator.h`? And calling C++ code from C is really not a good idea.

Comment: @NeilButterworth `Allocator` class and `include`'s to other header (C++). Yes, I am aware of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not post your command lines but I think that -lstdc++ (that is invoked automatically by g++) is missing from those.

Comment: Using `g++` to link instead of `gcc` would work, and you do imply that.  I think your answer would be better to actually state that simply linking with `g++` instead of `gcc` also works.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like the allocator `Allocator` uses new and delete, and the link does not include a C++ library to satisfy the missing functions.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
gcc cclient.o allocator.o ...(all other c++ objectives)...
```

You are using the C compiler to link the objects.
This knows nothing about C++ or the libraries it uses.

```
g++ cclient.o allocator.o ...(all other c++ objectives)...
```

That should work as it not only links the objects but also includes the C++ standard libraries (that include new and delete).

Comment: That is true, I suppose it wasn't inferred from the question, but I would like (if possible) to use gcc for compiling (and linking) and not g++ -- Going to edit that